# I am trying to seperate the numbers to odd and even and then pass to to the url path using variable in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a get request from where I am taking all the id values , using json extractor I have extracted and named it id and used match number as -1

Now I want to pass this id variable into a post url paths

And this post requests are set inside a for each controller to run for required no of iterations

I have given for each controller values as
Input variable : id
Start index : 0
End index : ${id_matchNr}
Output var name : outid

Paths arelike

Post Path 1: [https://demo.qwe.com/blue${outid}](https://demo.qwe.com/blue$%7Boutid%7D)

Post Path 2:
[https://demo.qwe.com/blue${outid}](https://demo.qwe.com/blue$%7Boutid%7D)

I want to pass only even id numbers to path 1 and odd id numbers to path two

So I have used if controller and gave expression as
${outid}%2==0 to first path
And ${outid}%2!=0 to other if controller and placed the path 2 request
And checked the interpret condition

These two rqsts are in for each controller.

When I run the script I am getting a blank output for the post rqsts.

Can you please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [function or variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you put in the If Controller must evaluate to `true`, only this way the If Controller will run its children. In your case you're providing just a string.

You need to wrap it into i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) like:

```
${__jexl3(${outid}%2==0,)}
```

this way it should work as expected.

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)